# How to detect plus key in wpf?

Tags: c#, wpf, keyboard

I know i can use below code to determine the Enter key in keyboard

```
if (e.Key == Key.Return)
{
    // do something
}
```

But i want to know what is the code for "+" and "-" ?

Can anyone help me please.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

There are two sets. One in the keyboard side and the other in the keypad side.

For keboard use `Key.OemPlus` and `Key.OemMinus` and for keypad one use `Key.Add` and `Key.Subtract`.

Comment: it work on keyboard + and -, but when I press these keys from keypad it dose not work ?

Comment: Do you press any special key like Ctrl or Shift?

Comment: okay NiKhil, it work, but still a little issues, when i select the row from datagrid and press + it work but when it done the datagrid selected row =0. can i keep selected row after press key ?

Answer (score 4):

The entire list of keys is here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.key.aspx

`OemPlus` and `OemMinus` are correct, like Nikhil said.